# How do you modify an array in React state with a callback function and map through every element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have have an array defined in state for the first render. I'm trying to modify the array using a callback function that react automatically calls and provides the current state value for to ultimately map through every element but i'm receiving this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

```
let initialShapes = [
  { id: 0, type: 'circle', x: 50, y: 100 },
  { id: 1, type: 'square', x: 150, y: 100 },
  { id: 2, type: 'circle', x: 250, y: 100 },
];


export default function App() {
  const [shapes, setShapes] = useState(initialShapes);

  function handleClick() {
    

    setShapes(function(prevData) {
      prevData.map(prev => {
        return {
          ...prev,
          y: prev.y + 50
        }
    })
    });
  }
```

I tried using a callback function and map the callback value which is supposed to be an array but I'm receing this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: `prevData.map(prev => {` -> `return prevData.map(prev => {`

Comment: So simple and yet it seemed like a world away to me. Thank you for contributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the new array in the callback to `setShapes` or the state will be set to `undefined` (as that is returned from all functions by default).

This can be simplified with [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), as they implicitly return the body if it is only a single expression.

```js
setShapes(prevShapes => prevShapes.map(prev => ({...prev, y: prev.y + 50})));
```